# Is there a rule condition to check if the url is the front page?

Tags: rules, database

Just wondering if is there a rule condition to check if the url is the front page of the site?

Comment: cant do with php snippet?

Comment: what do you mean? using rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont think there is such a rule, but you can do this: add a rule for `User is going to view page` and in condition add PHP snippet and check for [`drupal_is_front_page()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_is_front_page/7) based on this add actions as desired.